# Python/Pandas - Sum dataframe items if indexes have the same month

Tags: python, pandas

I have this two DataFrames:

## Seasonal_Component:

```
# DataFrame that has the seasonal component of a time series

Date
2014-12   -1.08
2015-01   -0.28
2015-02    0.15
2015-03    0.46
2015-04    0.48
2015-05    0.37
2015-06    0.20
2015-07    0.15
2015-08    0.12
2015-09   -0.02
2015-10   -0.17
2015-11   -0.39
```

## Prediction_df:

```
# DataFrame with the prediction of the trend of that same time series
            Prediction  MAPE  Score
2015-11-01        7.93  1.83      1
2015-12-01        7.93  1.67      1
2016-01-01        7.92  1.71      1
2016-02-01        7.95  1.84      1
2016-03-01        7.94  1.53      1
2016-04-01        7.87  1.45      1
2016-05-01        7.91  1.53      1
2016-06-01        7.87  1.40      1
2016-07-01        7.84  1.40      1
2016-08-01        7.89  1.77      1
2016-09-01        7.87  1.99      1
```

What I need to do:
Check which Prediction_df index have the same months as the Seasonal_Component index and sum the correspondent seasonal component with the prediction, so the Prediction_df looks like this:

```
            Prediction  MAPE  Score
2015-11-01        7,54  1.83      1
2015-12-01        6.85  1.67      1
2016-01-01        7.64  1.71      1
2016-02-01        8.10  1.84      1
2016-03-01        8.40  1.53      1
2016-04-01        8.35  1.45      1
2016-05-01        8.28  1.53      1
2016-06-01        8.07  1.40      1
2016-07-01        7.99  1.40      1
2016-08-01        8.01  1.77      1
2016-09-01        7.85  1.99      1
```

Anyone available to enlight my journey?
I'm already on the "almost mad" stage trying to solve this.

## EDIT

Important note to make it clearer: I need to disconsider the year and consider only the month to make the sum. Something like "everytime that an April appears (doesn't matter if it is 2006 or 2025) I need to sum with the April value of the Seasonal_Component frame.

Comment: Any effort on your side? Am I correct in assuming that you want to subtract the values in `Seasonal_Component` from `Prediction_df['Prediction']`?

Comment: Actually I need to sum those values, when they have the same month.

Comment: take a look at `merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a data frame [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the date fields (month values), then a simple addition of the two fields. The date fields may require conversion from string values:

```
import datetime as dt
...

# IF DATES ARE REGULAR COLUMNS
seasonal_component['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(seasonal_component['Date']) 
seasonal_component['Month'] = seasonal_component['Date'].dt.month

predict_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(predict_df['Date'])
predict_df['Month'] = predict_df['Date'].dt.month

# IF DATES ARE INDICES
seasonal_component.index = pd.to_datetime(seasonal_component.index)
seasonal_component['Month'] = seasonal_component.index.month

predict_df.index = pd.to_datetime(predict_df.index)
predict_df['Month'] = predict_df.index.month
```

However, think about how you need to join the two data sets (akin to SQL's join clauses):

- inner (default) - *keeps only records matching both*
- left  - *keeps records of predict_df and only those matching seasonal_component where predict_df is first argument*
- right - *keeps records of seasonal_component and only those matching predict_df where predict_df is first argument*
- outer - *keeps all records, those that match and those that don't match*

Below assumes an outer join where data on both sides remain with `NaNs` to fill for missing values.

```
# MERGING DATA FRAMES
merge_df = pd.merge(predict_df, seasonal_component[['Month', 'SeasonalComponent']], 
                    on=['Month'], how='outer')

# ADDING COLUMNS
merge_df['Prediction'] = merge_df['Prediction'] + merge_df['SeasonalComponent']
```

**Outcome** *(using posted data)*

```
         Date  Prediction  MAPE  Score  Month  SeasonalComponent
0  2015-11-01        7.54  1.83      1     11              -0.39
1  2015-12-01        6.85  1.67      1     12              -1.08
2  2016-01-01        7.64  1.71      1      1              -0.28
3  2016-02-01        8.10  1.84      1      2               0.15
4  2016-03-01        8.40  1.53      1      3               0.46
5  2016-04-01        8.35  1.45      1      4               0.48
6  2016-05-01        8.28  1.53      1      5               0.37
7  2016-06-01        8.07  1.40      1      6               0.20
8  2016-07-01        7.99  1.40      1      7               0.15
9  2016-08-01        8.01  1.77      1      8               0.12
10 2016-09-01        7.85  1.99      1      9              -0.02
11        NaT         NaN   NaN    NaN     10              -0.17
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait for your very complete answer, but I need to disconsider the year and consider only the month to make the sum. Something like "everytime that an April appears (doesn't matter if it is 2006 or 2025) I need to sum with the April value of the Seasonal_Component frame. Got it?

Comment: See update. Simply create month columns from date fields and merge on it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly separate the month from both dataframes and then merge on basis of month. Further add the required columns and create new column with desired output. Here is the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame,Series
from numpy.random import randn

Seasonal_Component = DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2014-12','2015-01','2015-02','2015-03','2015-04','2015-05','2015-06','2015-07','2015-08','2015-09','2015-10','2015-11'],
    'Value': [-1.08,-0.28,0.15,0.46,0.48,0.37,0.20,0.15,0.12,-0.02,-0.17,-0.39]
})


Prediction_df = DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2015-11-01','2015-12-01','2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2016-03-01','2016-04-01','2016-05-01','2016-06-01','2016-07-01','2016-08-01','2016-09-01'],
    'Prediction': [7.93,7.93,7.92,7.95,7.94,7.87,7.91,7.87,7.84,7.89,7.87],
    'MAPE':[1.83,1.67,1.71,1.84,1.53,1.45,1.53,1.40,1.40,1.77,1.99],
    'Score':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
})


def mon_extract(date):
    return date.split('-')[1]

Seasonal_Component['Month']=Seasonal_Component['Date'].apply(mon_extract)


def mon_extract(date):
    return date.split('-')[1].split('-')[0]


Prediction_df['Month']=Prediction_df['Date'].apply(mon_extract)


FinalDF=pd.merge(Seasonal_Component,Prediction_df,on='Month',how='right')


FinalDF


FinalDF['PredictionF']=FinalDF['Value']+FinalDF['Prediction']

FinalDF.loc[:,['Date_y','PredictionF','MAPE','Score']]
```

Comment: This error occurred probably due to datatype conversion issue.
 Try Extracting month using following methodology:
In [15]: t = pandas.tslib.Timestamp.now()
In [16]: t
Out[16]: Timestamp('2014-08-05 14:49:39.643701', tz=None)

In [17]: t.to_datetime()
Out[17]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 5, 14, 49, 39, 643701)

In [18]: t.day
Out[18]: 5

In [19]: t.month
Out[19]: 8

In [20]: t.year
Out[20]: 2014.

Comment: I'm not able to access the 'Date' column that way, since that's the index. I'm accessing through Seasonal_Component.index. However, when I use Seasonal_Component['Month']=Seasonal_Component.index.apply(mon_extract) I get the following error: AttributeError: 'PeriodIndex' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: I was able to access index and to apply the function using season['Month']=mon_extract(season.index). However all the 'Month' items come as 12', '2015, and I have no idea what that means. Any clue?

Comment: Try if you get correct output with Date.month 
or 
the other option you can have is simply converting Date datatype by taking Date and creating new column with date as string datatype. Further applying the method in new string column as in answer will help you resolve this.